How to solve a memory allocation problem to calculate a cosine_similarity
I have a file named articles_embeddings.pickle which you can find here: link
it contains 364,047 rows and 250 columns. Each row represents an article and each column represents a word vector.
To load this pickle file into python:

with open(MODEL_DIR_PATH + 'articles_embeddings.pickle', 'rb') as f:
articles_embeddings = cPickle.load(f) # deserialize using load()

My goal is to calculate the similarity between two articles, which means between two rows of the dataset. Given that there are 364,047 rows, we will have a result of size (364,047, 364,047) where each element is a ratio between 0 and 1 representing the similarity between two articles. To accomplish this, I use a built-in Python function: "cosine_similarity".
here is the python code:

from sklearn.metrics.pairwise import cosine_similarity
cosine_similarities = cosine_similarity(articles_embeddings)

Unfortunatly, I have a error return. Here is the output:
MemoryError: Unable to allocate 494. GiB for an array with shape (364047, 364047) and data type float32
The amount of memory required is too high. In my case (a PC with a CPU and 16GiB RAM), it works if I limit the size of the articles_embeddings dataframe to 40,000 rows. My question is: how can I accomplish this task with my limit hardware? Thanks for your return
I limited the number of rows and it works for 40 000 rows max

cosine_similarity is not built-in Python function but rather built-in sklearn function
